# Generic handle that auto releases resource

Tags: c++, boost, stl

Is there a generic handle class in STL or boost?  I am interfacing with some C code that has an alloc, release api.  I'd like to use a handle to auto release resource.

For example:

```
some_resource_type rsc;  
int err = capi_alloc(&rsc);
if (err != NOERR) {
   // .. do work with resource

   capi_release(rsc);
}
```

I want something like

```
// looking for this class
class wrapper { 
public:
     wrapper(T obj, void (del)(T&)):obj(obj_),del_(del) {}
     ~wrapper() {_del(obj);}
     T obj_;
     void (del_)(T&);
};

some_resource_type rsc;  
int err = capi_alloc(&rsc);
wrapper w;
if (err != NOERR) {
    w = wrapper(rsc, &capi_release);
    // .. do work with resource
}  
// then auto release
```

anything like this in STL or boost?   It's essentially some unique pointer implementation with custom create and custom delete.

P.S. I haven't compiled the wrapper code, it may not work.

Comment: Someone asked this a while back. You haven't searched.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I spent 30 minutes researching.  I probably didn't use the right key words.  If you know where, please post a link, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `std::unique_ptr` only supports heap allocation and no custom allocators, you could roll up your own stack-based wrapper class:

```
template<class T, int (& Allocator)(T*), void (& Deallocator)(T*)>
class wrapper {
public:
    wrapper() : err_(Allocator(&obj_)) {}
    ~wrapper() { if (err_ != NOERR) Deallocator(&obj_); }
    T& obj() { return obj_; }
    int err() { return err_; }
private:
    T obj_;
    int err_;
};
```

And use it like this:

```
wrapper<some_resource_type, capi_alloc, capi_release> rsc;  // capi_alloc called
if (rsc.err() != NOERR) {
    // .. do work with rsc.obj()
}
// capi_release called when rsc goes out of scope (if err_ != NOERR)
```

If you don't know what the allocator and deallocator functions are at compile time, then just pass them to the constructor and store as member data.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a *smart pointer*, and these are in recent C++ and in almost all in-the-wild meetable Boost variants; if you're using C++11, replace `boost` by `std`:

- `boost::shared_ptr`
- `boost::weak_ptr`

Comment: Smart pointers would allocate `some_resource_type` dynamically. As I understood it, the OP wants to allocate it on the stack.

Comment: You're right: if you declare your smart ptr on the stack, the thing it points at must be allocated off the heap.  When the smart ptr goes out of scope it automatically cleans up the memory.

Comment: @zenith, and as Brian hinted to, that includes calling the destructor of your object, which might free whatever external ressource your object was keeping.

Comment: Smart pointers don't allocate anything at all. You give them already-allocated data and tell them how to delete it, and they simply clean up for you when they go out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually (ab)use `std::unique_ptr` and its second template parameter (custom deallocator) for this:

```
std::unique_ptr<some_resource_type, void (&)(some_resource_type*)> w(nullptr, &capi_release);
```

And then in your `if`:

```
w.reset(&rsc);
```

A word of warning however: you **must** declare `w` *after* `rsc` with this approach. Otherwise `rsc` will be destroyed before `w` calls `capi_release` with it.

However since this is not the intended usage of `unique_ptr` I would recommend simply writing a small wrapper class as demonstrated in my other answer.

Comment: I tried this too, also works.  thanks.  I simplified the definition to std::unique_ptr<some_resource_type, decltype(&capi_release)> w(nullptr, &capi_release);  I hope you see that this question is helpful since the other one, although similar, does not include a generic answer.